# Firebase two database (iOS, Android)

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am quite new to firebase and using it for our iOS, Android chat app.

[image]

Previously, we only have 1 configuration (1 database). Now we need to have UAT and Prod env. As a result, I have created new DB in firebase but I don't know how to change database name in our mobile app.

Where/how can I write "alive-ios-10dfe" database name in our mobile app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Firebase documentation on connecting your app to multiple database instances](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding#connect_your_app_to_multiple_database_instances):

Swift:

> ```
> // Get the default database instance for an app
> var ref: DatabaseReference!
>
> ref = Database.database().reference()
>
>
> // Get a secondary database instance by URL
> var ref: DatabaseReference!
>
> ref = Database.database("https://testapp-1234.firebaseio.com").reference()
> ```

Android:

> ```
> // Get the default database instance for an app
> private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
> // ...
> mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
>
> // Get a secondary database instance by URL
> private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
> // ...
> mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://testapp-1234.firebaseio.com").getReference();
> ```

Note that it is more common to use separate projects for different environments. By having each environment on a separate project, they also get their own set of users, their own access tokens, and are separated in many more ways.